# How can I toggle between UTC and local time format for a kendo grid column?

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, timestamp, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with the first column as a Timestamp. I want an option in the column header which would toggle between the UTC and local time formats.

```
<div id="grid"></div>

<script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({
  columns: [ {
    field: "Timestamp",
    format: "{0: yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss}"
  }, {
    field: "number",
    format: "{0:c}"
  } ],
  filterable: true,
  dataSource: [ { Timestamp: new Date(), number: 3.1415 } ]
});
</script>
```

Can I use a kendo template here to give a condition to toggle between the time formats? I don't want to use the column format particularly.

Answer (score 0):

One option is you could use a column template and put each of the two formats in their own span with a class. Then you could have some button or toggle switch on the page that will hide/show the appropriate class through javascript/jquery.

Here's some kendo documentation for custom column templates:
https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid/configuration/columns.template